# How to get oobCode for localization purpose

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase allows only one language for confirmations emails. Whole nicely done products are useless for multi-language apps.  I want to make my own confirmation system. The only question is how can I get this oobCode which is generated inside firebase. site.com?mode=&oobCode=

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is currently no way to generate a valid `oobCode` value through the Firebase Authentication API. It can only be sent in the (as you've said "non-translatable") email message.

But you can build your own email verification mechanism if you want, using your own confirmation code to verify email ownership. You'd:

1. Generate a random, unguessable code on a server
2. Send it to the user's email address and then
3. When the user clicks the confirmation link, have your own end point on the same server that you call back to
4. At this point you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to set the `emailVerified` property to `true`.

For an example of the last step, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Thanks to @Nikhil in the comments: Alternatively you can roll your own verification altogether and use the Admin SDK to set `emailVerified` to true. See the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) for an example of that.

Comment: so we cannot use updateUser admin method if we do sendVerificationEmail() method on client? The updateUser method needs the uid and currently there is no way to send uid of the user in the email template correct?

Comment: Uhm... yes, good point. I forgot that the Admin SDK now updating user profiles. Alternatively you can indeed roll your own verification altogether and simply use the Admin SDK to set `emailVerified` to true. See the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) for an example of that.

Comment: thank you! Silly question - The getUser() or updateUser() updates UserRecord object, I would still need to update the fields in the database for the user at my /users/uid location. Correct?

Comment: There is no implicit connection between a user node in the database and the user's record in Firebase authentication. Any such connection is made by your code, so much also be maintained (updated in this case) by your code.

Comment: This solution does not work in its entirety today.  If you set up your own verification system, you won't be able to update the user's password in the event that they require a password reset.  You have to use the Firebase SDK to update the password using their `oobCode` which means you have to let the Admin SDK generate the links.  You can do that by spinning up a Firebase Function, use Admin SDK to generate these link, then use an email provider like SendGrid to send the email. This will also save you a lot of time.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links

Answer (score 0):

For NodeJS, here is how you generate an oob code similar to Firebase.

```js
import crypto from "crypto";

function generateCode() {
  // 54 length base64 string
  let code = crypto.randomBytes(40).toString("base64");
  // remove padding
  code = code.replace(/=+$/, "");
  return code.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_");
}
```