# firebase auth generate action code

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm using firebase auth with node.js.

follow code is not modify mail template for mail auth.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
```

i'm find firebase applyActionCode function

```
firebase.auth().applyActionCode(actionCode)
```

but i'm not find generate actionCode anywhere firebase document.

please help me.

generate actionCode or etc soultion.

thanks.

Comment: There is currently not way to generate an oobCode without sending a verification email. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515432/how-to-get-oobcode-for-localization-purpose/41516647#41516647

Comment: thanks. @FrankvanPuffelen
i try your link.